# IOS external dac

Tags: smartphones

I'm thinking about purchasing an external Dac for my iPhone to improve volume and quality of music I listen to when out and about.

I understand when I upgrade from the 6 to the iPhone 7, I will be forced to use an external Dac if I want to keep the same headphones I'm using now? Betron B750s.

Any Dac recommendations? I don't want something which drains the iPhones battery.

Been looking at Dragonfly black/reds, anyone using one of these?